# Encrypting Altbeacons

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am attempting to create UUID's that incorporate security measures that prevent replay attacks.  I plan to attach a timestamp to the UUID and Encrypt the beacon.  The encryption creates a 16 byte object but The Beacon Transmitter requires the UUID to be a string of consistent length. Is there a way I can transmit a Byte object instead of string.  Also, I need the encrypted beacon to change with the time.  Should I do a:
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon); 
    timeout(1 second);
    beaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising(beacon);
and recursively call my beacontransmit method?

Answer (score 0):

If your encryption really makes a 16 byte object, then you should be able to convert it to a UUID, which is also 16 bytes long.  It should be as simple as:

```
Identifier uuid = Identifier.fromBytes(byteArrayOfLength16, 0, 15, false);
```

However, encryption algorithms typically make a much longer byte array as the output.  You could remove all but 16 of the bytes from the encrypted output to make a hash (this is basically what Eddystone-EID does), but this won't be able to be decrypted.  The receiving device would have to perform the same encryption calculation for a given timestamp to see if it calculates the same value.  If it does, it knows it has found a match.

Yes, the approach of starting advertising based on one timestamp, waiting for a delay, and starting advertising based on a new timestamp is certainly the way to go.